# Dynamic import in page.evaluate Playwright

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, playwright

I have following Problem:
I want to call specific api endpoints in my playwright tests to improve my e2e tests.
Therefore i need to store the api URIS. The api endpoints are loaded via an script that is referenced in the `index.html`. This script adds a `config` property to the `window` object. This works well for the browser but not for the node environment where the playwright tests are executed. Of course i can use page.evaluate to access browser globals but i have another script `parseEndpoint.ts` that exposes query strings based on the base urls provided on the window object.This script needs to be imported at the top(not in the context of the playwright test) But there is no window defined. I tried to dynamically import the `parseEndpoint` script but all dynamic imports that are done in the tests begin with `localhost:port/pathToModule`(Literally no clue why). If i could delay the import of the module the problem would be solved.

Here are the scripts:

parseEndpoint.ts

```
export type WindowConfig = Window & typeof globalThis & { config: EndpointConfig };

const config = (window as WindowConfig).config;

export default {
    config
};
```

Snippet index.html:

```
   <script type="application/javascript" src="%BASE_URL%loadEndpoint.js"></script>
```